# Convert uploaded text file into a DataFrame in Python Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am exploring dash to build a dashboard for log analysis . I did my analysis in Jupyter Notebook but having tough time to reciprocate the same in Dash. After hours of research, I am unable to figure out how to convert a convert a text file into a DataFrame in Dash.

- I would need to do something as below in Dash.

```
def ReadLogFile(LogFile):
    with open(LogFile) as f:
        Log = f.readlines()
    Log = [x.strip() for x in Log]
    return Log

def Profiles_Submitted(LogFile):
    """
    This method searches for the pattern "Submitting Task For Execution" to list all the profiles
    submitted in the log file
    """
    filterLines = ReadLogFile(LogFile)
    OutputLines = []
    for line in filterLines:
        if re.search('Submitting Task For Execution', line):
            OutputLines.append(line)
    return OutputLines

..... Bunch of Functions in-between ....


def Profiles_Submitted_Clean_DataFrame(LogFile):
    """
    The DataFrame processes source datatype to required datatypes
    """
    process_df = Profiles_Submitted_Raw_DataFrame(LogFile)
    process_df ['Profile Job Date'] = pd.to_datetime(process_df ['Profile Job Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d').astype(str)
    process_df['Profile Job Time'] = pd.to_datetime(process_df['Profile Job Time']).dt.time
    return (process_df)
```

I have found samples in Dash Documentation where we can import xlsx or csv files and convert them to , Data tables but I find them not that helpful in context of text files.

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-data',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop or ',
            html.A('Select Files')
        ]),
        style={
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '60px',
            'lineHeight': '60px',
            'borderWidth': '1px',
            'borderStyle': 'dashed',
            'borderRadius': '5px',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'margin': '10px'
        },
        # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
        multiple=True
    ),
    html.Div(id='output-data-upload'),
])


def parse_contents(contents, filename, date):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    
    try:
        if 'csv' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
            
            df = pd.read_csv(
                io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
        elif 'xls' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return html.Div([
            'There was an error processing this file.'
        ])

    return html.Div([
        html.H5(filename),
        html.H6(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date)),

        dash_table.DataTable(
            data=df.to_dict('records'),
            columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns]
        ),

        html.Hr(),  # horizontal line

        # For debugging, display the raw contents provided by the web browser
        html.Div('Raw Content'),
        html.Pre(contents[0:200] + '...', style={
            'whiteSpace': 'pre-wrap',
            'wordBreak': 'break-all'
        })
    ])


@app.callback(Output('output-data-upload', 'children'),
              [Input('upload-data', 'contents')],
              [State('upload-data', 'filename'),
               State('upload-data', 'last_modified')])


def update_output(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates):
    if list_of_contents is not None:
        children = [
            parse_contents(c, n, d) for c, n, d in
            zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates)]
        return children
```

Can anyone help me/point me in the right direction on out how to import a text file then find desired patterns in it and convert to dataframes as I am doing in Jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

The example you gave is all you need if the file being uploaded is already formatted in a standard way, such as CSV. If you're dealing with unstructured files, then you can start from the same place, but you'll have to replace this line:

`df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))`

with your own code that gets from the decoded data to a formatted data frame. It looks like you may have some of that code already, so it should be a matter of finding which point of decoding the uploaded file, such as `decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)`, is most convenient for you to pass things over to your own code. You may be able to do this directly, but I haven't tried it to confirm:

`Log = io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')).readlines()`